# Does human skeletal muscle fascia grow new additional collagen in response to increases in skeletal muscle size?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, physiology, human-anatomy, anatomy

For example, if a human skeletal muscle is growing repeatedly due to periodic weightlifting, does the fascia eventually respond to the increasing volume by growing more quantities of collagen or other components to accommodate the growth? Or rather, does it only expand by "stretching" the existing amount of collagen without the growth of new material to accommodate the changes in muscle size (except perhaps to repair possible wear/damage that might've occurred during exercise)?